# Show that $\dot{n_s}=-\kappa_s t$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, self-learning

I found the question in a differential geometry textbook while studying. This question seems so intesting to me. So please help me solving it.

> Show that, if $\gamma$ is a unit-speed plane curve, $$\dot{\mathbf{n}}_s=-\kappa_s\mathbf t.$$

I know that

$$\dot t =\kappa_s n_s$$ and $$\kappa =|\kappa_s|$$

Comment: Also, can you write in LaTex since if someone wants to search a question like yours they will be able to do so? The way your question is formatted now they wont be able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

$\langle \mathbf n_s, \mathbf t_s \rangle = 0,\tag {1}$

whence

$\frac{d}{ds}\langle \mathbf n_s, \mathbf t_s \rangle = 0, \tag{2}$

so that

$\langle \dot{\mathbf n}_s, \mathbf t_s \rangle + \langle \mathbf n_s, \dot{\mathbf t}_s \rangle = 0, \tag{3}$

and using

$\dot {\mathbf t}_s =\kappa_s \mathbf n_s \tag{4}$

we get from (3)

$\langle \dot{\mathbf n}_s, \mathbf t_s \rangle = -\kappa_s \tag{5}$

since $\langle \mathbf n_s, \mathbf n_s \rangle = 1$.  And since $\langle \mathbf n_s, \dot{\mathbf n}_s \rangle = 0$ and we are operating in $\Bbb R^2$, we can conclude that

$\dot {\mathbf n}_s =  -\kappa \mathbf t_s. \tag{6}$

QED!

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***